# Is it safe to expose Stripe charge id and account Id of connected account to client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, stripe-payments

I have an ajax call I am doing to my backend and I was wondering if it's safe to expose the `charge id` and the `connected account id` to the client side?

I **don't** have any secret keys or anything on the browser side.

Thanks!

i call this once the refund button is clicked on:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {amount: pennies.toFixed(0), charge: chargeId, account: accountId},
            url: "/refund",
            success: function(data){
          //f.e. set to modal
          $('#refund_dialog').modal('hide')
            $('#refund_dialog').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                  })

        },
        error: function(err) {
            $('#refund_dialog').modal('hide')

            $('#refund_dialog').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    alert(err.responseText);
                  })
    });
```

Comment: I would say that you should never expose anything client-side unless absolutely necessary. Once the information is sent to the client, the client can modify that information however they please, which means your site could be used by hackers to forge fake account information etc

Comment: @mike510a well it's not like I'm exposing my secret keys. I am still doing the refund charge itself on my backend server. Take a look above, I added my ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, these IDs are not useful without API keys.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, but why you need to do so?

Comment: as in the above comment, he said unless absolutely necessary.
keep in mind this situation he mentioned.
Not a best practice I think.

Sorry I can't comment only on my answer as my reputation isn't soo much yet 

Comment: I have a query im doing to display order details regarding the charge on a website. I have a button where the user can press to refund the charge. So since the charge details are being queried to show up I have access to the ID as well as the user's Stripe account id. So once they press refund button, it sends a ajax call with the refund amount, charge id, and account id.

Comment: Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: connected account id and chargeId can be stored in DB for every user and do this logic with Stripe API on the server not throw a jquery function.
you can send to the client data needed to know who is the user and the charge with your DB id, not Stripe data.

Answer (score 0):

### It is *NOT* safe.

What would happen if a hacker decided to create a program that makes millions of requests for refunds by entering in random  account IDs, charge ID and refund IDs?

The result could be that thousands of refunds  are requested...

Instead you should store all of this data (account ID, charge ID and refund ID) into a table in a database on the server that is handling the transaction (or forwarding it).

The three pieces of data should be stored using a key that is generated using some a UUID generator such as OpenSSL to ensure no conflicting  IDs are generated.

The UUIUD should be the key for the data in the database.

The refund button should simply send that same UUID via AJAX, at which point the server will look up the necessary data with the UUID and then send the relevent data via  Stripe.

---

### Another reason why its NOT safe

By returning the account ID back to the user, if they have a web browser which has been compromised by malicious extensions / add-ons / plugins / etc,  then now a hacker could get ahold of the user's account ID giving them a crucial piece of information that they could use to forge other requests etc.

### Never assume that data sent to the client will be reliably received or returned.

Data should only be sent to the client if that data is to be displayed to the client (such as a  page which has their account ID on it).

At the same time, the data sent to the client should NEVER be used as input for any server-side operations as this allows for requests to be forged, potentially letting a hacker access your back-end systems.

### Another way its not safe

If a hacker is familiar with your back-end system (Stripe or whatever), then they can determine your API secret key if they are able to perform a Man In the Middle  type of attack on your server by forwarding network requests to and from remote locations. This could allow for a different part of your site  completely unconnected to any Stripe interactions to be a gateway that could allow them to send specially crafted requests (with random account ID, charge ID, amount) , and then see the data after it is encrypted with your API Key, and be able to decode that data in order to get your secret API key.

Instead, by using a UUID, a hacker has no way of connecting the two pieces of the puzzle together, thus making it safe from M.I.T.M. attacks.

Comment: So from what your saying, Stripe should also revise their dashboard as well because they show account id's, charge id's, refund id's, customer id's etc. I suppose there site is vulnerable too.

Comment: stripes servers are not forwarding data to and from a third party . these vulnerabilities mostly arise from using 3rd party apis

Comment: and it might be vulnerable..  perhaps something they should look at

Comment: If you are sure that none of those vulnerabilities are threats to your server, as well as any other possible vulnerabilities out there, then you can be assured that its safe... otherwise assume that its not safe to expose any information to the client without knowing which vulnerabilities exist for your particular software